# getaddrinfo and INADDR_ANY

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, getaddrinfo

Spent a couple of hours searching, still puzzled. From what I've found, INADDR_ANY is meant to specify that the socket will accept connections with any address that is assigned to the server. The following, however, results in the client only being able to connect to `localhost:7777` from the same machine.

```
addrinfo hints;
addrinfo* result;
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
getaddrinfo(INADDR_ANY, "7777", &hints, &result);

SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
listenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

bind(listenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
```

The only solution that I've found is to change INADDR_ANY to the machine's local IP:

```
getaddrinfo("192.168.0.105", "7777", &hints, &result);
```

I need to understand how INADDR_ANY works, because I feel like I'm just misusing it somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `INADDR_ANY` has the effect you expect ***when it is passed as a parameter directly to `bind()`***. You're not doing it. You're passing this value to `getaddrinfo()`. Which is a completely different story. Now, why don't you examine what `getaddrinfo()`returns, in this case, and figure this out yourself. If you want to accept connections on any local IP address, you don't need `getaddrinfo()`. Get rid of this whole thing, in its entirety, and call `bind()` directly.

Comment: How do you even know if `getaddrinfo()` even *worked*?  You're not bothering to check the return value.  Per [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html):  "A zero return value for `getaddrinfo()` indicates successful completion; a non-zero return value indicates failure. The possible values for the failures are listed in the ERRORS section."

Comment: `getaddrinfo` can return *several* addresses; and you also need to `freeaddrinfo(result)`  yet you ever bind the first one only.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I omitted the error checking for brevity sake, my bad.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry I'm a bit confused: how can we skip `getaddrinfo` and directly use `bind()`? like, if so how do we know the address to bind to?

Comment: You know it, @Crystina, because it is what you directly specify to `bind()`. See `bind()`'s documentation for more information. You specify `INADDR_ANY` as the address to bind to. The End.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INADDR_ANY` has nothing to do with your issue.

The first parameter of `getaddrinfo()` is a `const char *` specifying an IP address or hostname. But `INADDR_ANY` is an integer instead. The only reason your code even compiles is because `INADDR_ANY` is defined as integer constant 0, which is the only integer constant that is allowed to be assigned to a pointer. So, you are actually passing NULL to the first parameter. Which is fine in this situation, as that is what you need anyway.

What you are not taking into account is that `getaddrinfo()` returns a *linked list* of addresses, which may contain multiple addresses, *especially* if you use `AF_UNSPEC`. Using that family tells `getaddrinfo()` that it can return addresses for *both* IPv4 and IPv6. But you are only using the first address in the list, which just happens to correspond to `localhost` (127.0.0.1 in IPv4, ::1 in IPv6).

For a server, you *should* be creating and binding a separate listening socket for *each* address in the output list. That will let you bind to all of the addresses that match the criteria you passed to `getaddrinfo()`, eg:

```
addrinfo hints = {};
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

addrinfo* result;

if (getaddrinfo(NULL, "7777", &hints, &result) == 0)
{
    for (addrinfo *addr = result; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
    {
        SOCKET listenSocket = socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
        if (listenSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            bind(listenSocket, addr->ai_addr, (int)addr->ai_addrlen);
            listen(listenSocket, ...);
            // store listenSocket in a list for later use... 
        }
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
}

// use listening sockets as needed...
```

Alternatively, as Sam V mentioned in comments, you can skip `getaddrinfo()`, it is not really helping you in this situation. You could just create and bind 2 sockets directly, one for IPv4 and one for IPv6:

```
SOCKET listenSocket4 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (listenSocket4 != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    sockaddr_in addr = {};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(7777);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(listenSocket4, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(listenSocket4, ...);
}

SOCKET listenSocket6 = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (listenSocket6 != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    sockaddr_in6 addr = {};
    addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    addr.sin6_port = htons(7777);
    addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

    bind(listenSocket6, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(listenSocket6, ...);
}

// use listening sockets as needed...
```

Or better, create and bind a single [dual-stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665.aspx) socket that supports *both* IPv4 and IPv6:

```
SOCKET listenSocket = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (listenSocket != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    BOOL off = FALSE;
    setsockopt(listenSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (char*)&off, sizeof(off));

    sockaddr_in6 addr = {};
    addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    addr.sin6_port = htons(7777);
    addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

    bind(listenSocket, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(listenSocket, ...);
}

// use listening socket as needed...
```

Comment: Thank you, the last 2 options are what I what I was looking for. The guides I managed to find were all old and narrow in their scope, and this being the first time that I write netcode without a framework to help me, I didn't know anything about how the API is supposed to work.